# Understand the dependency levels of makefiles

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

Assume that the project has the following files, where the first files is dependent on the files under it's category in the unordered list:

- main.c

  - global.h         (contains enumerations and #define macros)
  - sdlevent.h       (generic header file)

    - sdlevent.c   (contains implementations of sdlevent.h)
  - sdlshape.h       (generic header file)

    - sdlshape.c   (contains implementations of sdlshape.h)

Now, I have the following makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -w -std=c99
LIBS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf

SRCS = main.c sdlshape.c sdlevent.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
EXE = play

all: $(EXE)

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

$(OBJS): global.h sdlevent.h sdlshape.h

run : all
    ./$(EXE)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ $(EXE)
```

> The target `$(EXE)` is dependent on the target `.c.o`. Do I absolutely need to define the target `$(EXE)` *after* the target `.c.o`?

I don't think so, because even though the target `$(EXE)` is dependent on the target `$(OBJS)`, the target `($EXE)` is declared *before* `$(OBJS)`.

Comment: Cmake has better tutorials and is a more general tool that generates make files. I highly suggest checking it out.

Comment: @SimonHobbs, AFAIK, make is the most general building tool. But if you say that Cmake is then I will check it out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @klaus I'm not sure, but I think it is best to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I absolutely need to define the target $(EXE) after the target .c.o?

First, `.c.o` is not a target, it's a *suffix rule*.

Second, `make` does not care what sequence targets are written in, so the answer is "no". The whole makefile is read and when a target is missing, a lookup is performed for a rule to create the target. Technically, `make` creates a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG) of targets and dependencies before it considers building anything. Variable references are replaced when they are used, not when they are read (exception: GNU make's `:=` assignment operator).

Try playing around with the order of targets. You can even move the variable assignments to the bottom.

I'm sure there are a few esoteric corners in GNU make where things work slightly differently, but in a simple makefile as yours, not straying too far from a POSIX makefile, that's how it works.